# Get access to parent WPF window across AppDomain

Tags: wpf, winapi, appdomain

I am developing an AddIn for SCVMM (System center for Hyper-V), It is a WPF application that allows users to develop Add-Ins and host their WPF UI (user controls) inside of SCVMM. It uses the Microsoft Add-ins and Extensibility framework.

I am trying to access the parent window instance, the main SCVMM window that hosts my add-in. I have searched on this topic and everybody says it is not possible to do this across App domains.

I am able to get the handle to the window but when i try to convert it into a window I get null.

```
     HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(this.btn);
     IntPtr handle2 = source.Handle;

     Window w = source.RootVisual as Window;
```

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Are you sure you really need window, and handle is not enough for your purposes (what are you going to do with window)?. 2) Are you sure that rootVisual is Window and not something else, like ElementHost?

Comment: Yes I need the actual window instance, I am able to use the handle to set the owner for the child dialog, but we have some requirements that need to get access to the AddIn button on the SCVMM window, So if I can get a handle to the window, I will be able to traverse the visual tree and get access to the AddIn button. 2) you are right rootvisual is not a window, it is a contentcontrol, and it is not the content control of SCVMM window, it is jsut returning me my Add-In control